# Tesseract OCR wrapper para net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ocr, tesseract

Estoy buscando un wrapper de tesseract que funcione con .net core; actualmente cuando agrego el package tesseract de nuget obtengo el warning:

```
Package 'Tesseract 3.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' 
instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: traduce tu pregunta al español, pues estas en la versión al castellano, me temo que de lo contrario te la van a cerrar

Comment: gracias Shadow, editada.